# Why does my static css file is not reflecting on my browser using flask?

Tags: python, css, flask, static, mime-types

I should have a webpage with a purple background and blue font color, but my browser is rendering it as plain HTML without any CSS styling. The console returns a status code of 200, indicating that everything is okay, but the webpage still appears as plain HTML in my browser. However, when I manually edit the CSS file to the source using the inspect element in my browser, I get the desired output.

I've also tested it on my friend's devices, and it works as expected on their end. Unfortunately, I'm still experiencing the issue on my own device.

I've tried several solutions, including reinstalling PyCharm and Python, as well as testing it with Visual Studio Code and different browsers like Edge, Firefox, and Chrome. However, the problem persists, and the webpage remains plain HTML when I run it. I also hard refreshed it multiple times and emptied my cache. Firefox gives me this error: `The stylesheet http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/style.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “application/x-css”, is not “text/css”.`

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

static/styles.css

```
body {
    background-color: purple;
}

h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">
<!--    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" **I tried this too />-->
</head>
<body>
<h1>I'm Ben</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If your `templates` folder is in the same folder as the `static` folder, your CSS link need to look like this: `../static/styles.css`. This is called a relative link, though. It's better to set up an absolute link, or "root relative" link (which will work from all pages on the site), but this is better than nothing.

Comment: Just saying your code doesn't work without explaining what it does (or doesn't) do is not a good question. You should explain what happens and what you expect including any errors. You question may be difficult to answer without this type of detail and end up relegated. See [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I've also attempted using the relative file path, @ralph.m However, the issue continues to persist despite this approach.

Comment: Hello, I just resolved this issue by adding these lines of code to my `main.py`:

```python
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('text/css', '.css') ```